# Create image in Google Cloud uploading VMDK

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create private image in Google Cloud uploading a VMDK file. I did it first converting the vmdk to RAW format which turns my 2.7 GB vmdk to near about 50 GB RAW. Due to this its taking 8-10 hr to upload in google storage. Is there any other way to upload parallel to make it faster or is there any other approach by which we can upload to image to Google Storage without converting it to RAW ?

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images? Please make sure you use --sparse option with tar - this will reduce the size of your uploaded file.